# Async Task Implementation Issues

Tags: java, android, http, post, android-asynctask

I have no idea what I've done wrong - but I'm getting having several issues with compiling the following code after combining the source code from two different files I had. Any suggestions as to what could be causing these issues (as a learning experience) and if it's not too complicated a way to resolve them is appreciated.

(Thanks in advance!)

JAVA:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class AddEditCountry extends Activity {

     private long rowID; 
     private EditText nameEt;
     private EditText capEt;
     private EditText codeEt;
     private TimePicker timeEt;


            private EditText value;
            private Button btn;
            private ProgressBar pb;
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.deviceconfig);
                value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                nameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
                  capEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.capEdit);
                  codeEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.codeEdit);
                  timeEt = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);




                  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

                  if (extras != null)
                  {
                     rowID = extras.getLong("row_id");
                     nameEt.setText(extras.getString("name"));  
                     capEt.setText(extras.getString("cap"));  
                     codeEt.setText(extras.getString("code"));    
                     String time = extras.getString("time");
                     String[] parts = time.split(":");
                     timeEt.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]));
                     timeEt.setCurrentMinute(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]));
                     timeEt.setIs24HourView(false);
                     DecimalFormat df =   new DecimalFormat  ("00");
                     String minutes = df.format(min);
            }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        (value.getText().toString());       
                    }{


            new MyAsyncTask().execute

             class AddEditCountry extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

                @Override
                protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    postData(params[0]);
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
                    pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
                }

                public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
                    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://gamedemo.hostzi.com/apply.cgi");

                    try {
                        // Add your data
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("submit_button", "Wireless_MAC"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("change_action", ""));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "Apply"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wl_macmode", "allow"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wl_maclist", "32"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wait_time", "3"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wl_mac_filter", "1"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", "allow"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("wl_macmode1", "allow"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m0", "00%3A1E%3A33%3AFE%3A0D%3A38"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m16", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m1", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m17", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m2", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m18", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m3", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m19", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m4", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m20", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m5", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m21", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m6", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m22", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m7", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m23", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m8", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m24", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m9", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m25", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m10", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m26", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m11", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m27", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m12", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m28", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m13", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m29", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m14", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m30", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m15", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m31", "00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00%3A00"));
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("end", ""));

                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        // Execute HTTP Post Request
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }





          Button saveButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
          saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                 if (nameEt.getText().length() != 0)
                 {
                    AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = 
                       new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() 
                       {
                          @Override
                          protected Double doInBackground(Object... params) 
                          {
                             saveContact();
                             return null;
                          }

                          @Override
                          protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
                          {
                             finish();
                          }
                       }; 

                    saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null); 
                 }

                 else
                 {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddEditCountry.this);
                    alert.setTitle(R.string.errorTitle); 
                    alert.setMessage(R.string.errorMessage);
                    alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.errorButton, null); 
                    alert.show();
                 }
              } 
         });
       }


           private void saveContact() 
           {
              DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);

              if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)
              {
                  dbConnector.insertContact(nameEt.getText().toString(),
                          capEt.getText().toString(),
                          timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                              + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                          codeEt.getText().toString());

              }
              else
              {
                 dbConnector.updateContact(rowID,
                         nameEt.getText().toString(),
                            capEt.getText().toString(),
                              timeEt.getCurrentHour().toString() + ":"
                                  + timeEt.getCurrentMinute().toString(),
                              codeEt.getText().toString());
              }
           }}
```

PROBLEMS:

```
    Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable  AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 116    Java Problem
The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (AddEditCountry)   AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 80 Java Problem
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 60 Java Problem
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements    AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 120    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 120    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 116    Java Problem
Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 116    Java Problem
Syntax error on token ".", = expected   AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 1  Java Problem
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)    AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 122    Java Problem
Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead AddEditCountry.java /app/Game Demo/src/com/app/gamedemo line 207    Java Problem
```

Comment: Why you have an inner class `DeviceConfig` activity?

Comment: your importing import com.nfc.linkingmanager.DeviceConfig.MyAsyncTask; remove it

Comment: move your asynctask class outside the method. Check the return type doInBackground().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see this is your problems:

1. Each of your `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(.. , ..);` need an extra `)` at the end.
2. You are missing a `}` to end the scope of your `AsyncTask` and I actually think you're missing 2 to end your inner class also (otherwise you have duplicate `onCreate` methods)
3. Your `MyAsyncTask` class have a `public` modifier. Remove it.
4. Your `doInBackground` method should return a `Double` not an `Object`
5. Your `AsyncTask` is now called `AddEditCountry` which is the same as your outer class. This is not possible. Change one of the names.
6. Your `AsyncTask` class is being defined *inside* your `onClick(View v)` method. Move the class out of the method. ¨
7. You cannot use `this` in `btn.setOnClickListener(this);` because the click listener needs to be an `OnClickListener`, which your class isn't. You can solve this by creating a new `OnClickListener` which implement your onClick method and pass that as the paramenter. (Like you have done with the save button)

I don't see why you have an inner Activity class. I suggest that you rethink whether you really want that inner activity, or you just want the methods/functionality from `DeviceConfig` in `AddEditCountry` or maybe they just should be in two different files.

EDIT(s): Listed more problems.

Comment: 1. I updated the source with the method you described! Things are looking better! (I updated my problems log above too - I'm still having a few)

2. I corrected the } issues (thanks!) I still have 4 bugs/problems left in it - any idea what those might be about?

Comment: 1. I added the 2nd )
2. I believe I corrected these as well (no longer appearing in the problems log)
3. Removed the public modifier 4. Changed from Object to Double 5. I belive I corrected this as well

6. I edited this - but I think there is a problem with it

7.  Removed btn.setOnClickListener(this); [not sure what to add or do from here]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a '}' at the end of your AsyncTask (before the onCreate)